# breaking proc entry from user into smaller strings

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am making a module in which I am taking some entries from user and breaking them into smaller strings and storing them into an array. The logic is working fine but after few minutes the kernel panics.Below I am giving the code for putting the entries to /proc file from user space and then the coding in module.

```
FILE *fp;
fp =fopen("/proc/tx_info","w");

fprintf(fp,"protocol   address      tos   payload interface");
fprintf(fp,"\n %3s %6s %7d %5d %6s\n",prot,addr,tos,pld,inter);
fclose(fp);
```

now the code in the module

```
void tx_break(void)
{
char ch;
char tmp[25];
int i =0;
int k=0,j=0,y = 0;

ch = tx_buffer[0];
//runing the while loop while the ch goes to next line from where the real user entries starts
while(ch != '\n')
     {
       ch = tx_buffer[i];
       i++;
     }


while(ch != '\0')
{
   j=0;
//while loop for blanks in between the user entries
   while(ch == ' ' && ch != '\0')
    {
      i++;
      ch = tx_buffer[i];
    }
//while loop to put the user defined entries to a temporary tmp which would become an entry of 2d array(info.arr[][])
  while(ch != ' ' && ch !='\0')
    {
       tmp[j] = ch;
       j++;
       i++;
       ch = tx_buffer[i];
    }
    tmp[j] = '\0';
    printk(KERN_ALERT"\n%s\n",tmp);
//putting user entries to an 2d array
    for(k=0;tmp[k] != '\0';k++)
         info.arr[y][k] = tmp[k];
         info.arr[y][k] = '\0';
    printk("the 2d::%s",&info.arr[y][0]);
    y++;
   // memcpy(&info.arr[k][0],tmp,j+1);
   // k++;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know how are you reading `tx_bufferp` so I suppose you have stored on it all information from `/proc/tx_info` file.

From here, I see some mistakes:

```
while(ch != '\n')
{
    ch = tx_buffer[i];
    i++;
}
```

Maintains ch = '\n' on last execution.

Now, with ch = '\n', `tmp[0] = "\n"`, you store it in `info.arr[0]` and prints its address. So, you have stored one non item in `info.arr`. Which is the dimension of this variable? Maybe you are storing out of bounds.

In last item processing, you are storing `\n` character too in `tmp` because `while(ch != ' ' && ch !='\0')`. Is this correct?